# How to calculate font-size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using `HTML` tags for my web site.

I have one HTML `<table>` with fixed height `150px`. Table content is filled Dynamical using JavaScript.
I want to set **dynamic** `font-size` for the table text-content as shown below.

**I also have the total count of Characters**

**HTML**

```
<table style="height:150px;width:350px;">
   <tr>
      <td>
         bla....bla...bla...   /* I want to set this font size dynamic*/
      <td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         bla....bla...bla...   /* I want to set this font size dynamic*/
      <td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**But** the problem is , I don't know the **formula** I should apply.
Please help me - I have the total count of characters according to length which formula I should apply for setting the `font-size` so the all characters should fit in table without `over lapping` and without scroll.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know the formula, what makes you think we do ?

Comment: Sarcastically: I always use dog tags for websites ;-)

Comment: calculation based on what? What are you trying to achieve? saying you want to calculate the font size does'nt mean much

Comment: @adeneo, @atmd - I mean e.g if I have 530 characters and my `table` height is 150px and width is 350px  - depend on that what should be the font-size which will fit all the characters inside table without `over lapping` it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the jQuery-plugin "FitText". (http://fittextjs.com/)

```
$("table tr td").fitText();
```

It automaticly changes the font-size in the div depending on its width.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vay0tf33/

Comment: Please explain your answer, how does this solve the problem of the OP?

Comment: What is the OP's problem? He didn't say he wants the text to fit its parent?

Comment: @atmd - yes I want to fit all characters in <table> tag

Comment: Up to the width of the table? I don't believe this is possible, you could get a close guess, but it wouldn't be accurate, I mean you haven't taken the font type into account or font weight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the width of the characters inside the table. You can do this with a function that wraps the content into a span and calculates the width in pixels. Then divide the result of that function with the width of the table. This should get you the rows. Dividing the height in pixels with the amount of rows should get you the maximum font-size in pixels.

```
function calculateFontSize(width, height, content){
     var area = width*height;
     var contentLength = content.length();

     return  Math.sqrt(area/contentLength); //this provides the font-size in points.

}
```

Important notes:

This function needs plain text input. As @atmd said you can only approximate the font size. The font-size needs to be in points `pt`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5yebL0k/

Comment: it's not return correct value - it's return 1.534.. something which is not correct :(

Comment: @prog, I think this should do it more or less. It's still an approximation and not a precise calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, its not great but will give you want you want

Firstly you'd need to create an element with `'visibility:hidden;display:inline;` as its style (css or inline, doesn't matter for this example). The element needs the text you want to measure.

```
<p id='hidden' style='visibility:hidden;display:inline;'>some thing here</p>
```

then in your scripts:

```
var text = document.getElementById('hidden'); // id of hidden element
```

Then if you use `text.offsetWidth` you'll get the width of the element
You can then create a loop in javascript to increase the font size until the offSetWidth is equal to the table width.

The above isnt a great way of doing things but it will give you exactly what you are looking for regardless of font type or weight etc